# How do I edit code alignment style with an attached code style?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

I want to fix code alignment style in visual studio.
I don't know how to edit code style that I want in tool option.

[image: custom code alignment style]

So I asked to chatGPT, but it did not answer that I want.
please help.
[image: Answer by ChatGPT]

If I Insert key
Ctrl + K, Ctrl + F or Ctrl + D

The default code alignment style irritates my eyes.
This isn't the style I'm going for.
[Default code alignment style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wC6VL.png)

Comment: Menu > Edit > Format Document - that's the answer - I know its "not answer that I want" but you dont request what you want?

Comment: Do you want to change format of document or how it should format? For first part, you  already have answer from ChatGPT. For second part, go to Tools > Options > Tex Editor > All Languages > Tabs.

Comment: If your first screenshot is the formatting you strive for then i think there is no option in the formatting settings to get there. Aligning by operators may be "eye pleasing" but i don't see that as readability improvement to easier understand code. When Visual Studio could do that and applies that to the complete code presumably most of that formatting you may see then wouldn't be helpful but more of a problem.

Answer (score 0):

For Text formatting in visual studio, you can use:

1. Ctrl+K Ctrl+F to format the selected text.
2. Ctrl+K Ctrl+D to apply the formatting to the entire file